# MySQL One to many, pulling only selected record from many table

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-many

I am quite new at SQL statements and I have never been very good at joins etc. I am having a problem working out how to do the following:

I have 2 tables, one called MUSIC, one called REVIEWS. The two tables link on a field called uid - records in MUSIC are unique, but there may be many reviews for each MUSIC record.

REVIEWS has a field called thumbsup, which is set to value 1 if a user gives a MUSIC the thumbs up. Otherwise, the field is zero. There may be many thumbsup in REVIEWS, one thumbsup, or no thumbsup.

I am trying to display a list of records in MUSIC, and if there is a corresponding REVIEW record that contains a thumbsup value of 1 - just one record in REVIEWS will do it - then to display an icon on the list page.

I have had a good look around various similar questions but nothing quite like this comes up. I have tried doctoring around similar kinds of joins, but frankly how it all works is beyond me. Sorry for being an idiot.

By way of evidence that I have at least had a go, so far I have come up with this based on another post:

```
SELECT m.*, r.thumbsup 
FROM (SELECT MAX(thumbsup) uid FROM reviews GROUP By uid) maxThumbs 
INNER JOIN reviews r ON maxThumbs.uid = reviews.uid 
INNER JOIN music m ON music.uid = reviews.uid
```

Needless to say it doesn't work :(

If anyone could help me out here with the right query structure I would be extremely grateful.

Many thanks

Ted.

Comment: you need votes sum for each record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT m.* from music m INNER JOIN reviews r on m.uid = r.uid where r.thumbsup > 0
```

Comment: -1, will select many music rows because of multiple reviews and also -1 for using SQL'89 implicit `where` joins.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
SELECT m.*, IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM reviews r WHERE r.thumbsup > 0 AND m.uid = r.uid LIMIT 1),0) has_review 
FROM music m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM music m
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT reviews.uid WHERE review.thumbsup > 0) r ON (r.uid = m.uid)
```

Comment: sorry about the delay in replying, I have been moving house.

But thanks loads for your answers, several of your examples worked, and I learned some new stuff as well.

So thanks for your help with that one.

All the best

Ted

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*, r.thumbsup
FROM music m LEFT JOIN reviews r 
ON (m.uid = r.uid AND r.thumbsup=1);
```

Will return music records with no reviews, no positive reviews, mixed reviews, postivie only reviews (with any positive reviews indicated)